# .gitlab-ci.yml: How to specify "only/except" rules with a regex AND repo-specific qualifier?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In the [`only` section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#only-and-except) of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` I can match a branch name by regex like:

```
  only:
    - /^issue-.*/
```

and match a branch name for a specific branch and repo like:

```
  only:
    - issue-123@mygroup/myproject
```

But how do I do both? I tried this:

```
  only: 
    - /^issue-.*@mygroup\/myproject/
```

but with no success.

I'm using GitLab Community Edition 8.17.4.

Comment: you use different project names. In regex you specify the the project name as `myproject` but in previous example you using the `my-project` name.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo when writing this question. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the group/project name part cannot be part of the regex in 8.17.

Testing with gitlab 8.17.5-ce, I can use regex for the branch name followed by string only group/project name to select specific branches to build on, like this:

```
  only:
  - /^issue-.*/@mygroup/myproject
```

In context:

```
stages:
 - build

build-any-issue-on-mygroup-myproject:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "hello"
  only:
    - /^issue-.*/@mygroup/myproject
```

Comment: describe your answer some more